Would every triangle have 3 concurrent cevians such that they intersect each other at $60^{\circ}$?
In an equilateral triangle, the three angle bisectors meet at the incenter. They intersect with each other forming angles of  $60^{\circ}$ with each other. Will every triangle have 3 concurrent cevians which intersect at  $60^{\circ}$ with each other? What would the coordinates of that point be for a triangle with coordinates $(a,b)$, $(m,n)$, $(x,y)$. I tried to find an answer using various methods but alas none of them lead me anywhere meaningful.

P.S. We can also make 3 lines intersecting each other at  $60^{\circ}$ in an equilateral triangle from each point, but in this case they just intersect in the exterior of the triangle. Will every triangle have an exterior point like this as well?


Hint: Read up on Fermat point.

Have you tried answering this yourself? What is the locus of points P for which the angle APB = $120^{\circ}$?

I was unaware of the term "cevian". For anyone else like me who had to look it up, it's any line that goes through one vertex and the opposite side. Medians and angle bisectors are specific examples of cevians.

@Arthur it comes from Ceva's theorem, which is about, well, cevians.

@JoseAvilez I know, I learned that when I had to look them up. I hadn't heard about Giovanni Ceva before, but I did actually know his theorem.
